# jQuery get class of an element which has 2 classes

Tags: jquery

```
<button class="update vacancy-submit" tabindex="2">Save</button>

$('.vacancy-submit').click(function(){
    var type = $(this).attr('class').not('.vacancy-submit');
    console.log(type);
});
```

I'm trying to get the class for button into a variable which should say `update` and not `update vacancy-submit`

Comment: _“which should say update and not update vacancy-submit”_ – based on what criteria exactly? The button _has_ two classes, so how would you want to get only one of them?

Comment: Question is not clear ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it's always the first class:

```
$('.vacancy-submit').click(function(){
    var type = this.className.split(/\s+/).shift();
    console.log(type);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bh8JT/)

Comment: @Kite Player: It works, but you need a console window open! Given the poor wording of the question, this seems the most practical solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace the unwanted portion of the class attribute value

```
var type = $.trim($(this).attr('class').replace('vacancy-submit', ''));
```

Comment: This then depends on knowing all the other classes that might be on the button so not very practical.

Comment: Granted the question wording is very poor, but hard-wiring a replace can never be a good option. Other JQuery components could easily add extra classes. Best to plan ahead for the worst. The suggestion by `adeneo` seems appropriate as unknown classes would be appended.

Comment: After thinking about the issues, I have added a JQuery `firstClass` JQuery extension answer as a cleaner/modular approach. Would be interested in your opinion of it.

Answer (score 0):

The following code will remove `vacancy-submit` from the string you get.

```
$('.vacancy-submit').click(function(){
    var type = $(this).attr('class').replace('vacancy-submit','');
    console.log(type);
});
```

Comment: This then depends on knowing all the other classes that might be on the button so not very practical.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to get the name of first class in class attribute

```
function classname() {
         var myClassName = $('#id').attr('class').split(' ');
        var firstName = myClassName[0];
      }
```

Comment: If the selector was not hardwired to '#id' this would also be a practical answer... suggest you pass the selector or maybe make this a JQuery extension?

Answer (score 0):

After much thinking about this, I would actually suggest you define the following JQuery extension to isolate the problem and make it a bit more reusable:

```
jQuery.fn.firstClass = function() {
    return this.attr('class') ? this.attr('class').split(' ')[0] : "";
   };
```

Then you simply have:

```
$('.vacancy-submit').click(function(){
    var type = $(this).firstClass();
    console.log(type);
});
```

### Updated JSFiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Bh8JT/1/

Has test cases for 0, 1 or more classes.